# Unable to import FigureCanvasWxAgg from Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib, pydev

I'm using Python x64 with everything installed, but I'm getting an unresolved import on FigureCanvasWxAgg.  I can get up to matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg but there's no FigureCanvasWxAgg to import from there.

I've also tried 
`from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import *` but it doesn't work either.

EDIT: Problem solved.  I took a peek at my backend_wxagg.py file and found it to be completely different than the one listed [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Chart-Report/Matplotlib/matplotlib-0.99.1.1/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py.htm).  So I copied that from version 0.99.1.1 into my 1.0.1 file.  (I should probably just uninstall 1.0.1 matplotlib and use the older version.)  Anyway, it got the examples working, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you on, and how did you install matplotlib?

Your solution is quite likely to break things... You need to build and install the wx backend as you normally would.  I'm not sure about the wx backend, but several of the other backends are C extensions, not just a simple python file.

The wx backend isn't built by default, so it's usually included as a separate package. (e.g. `python-matplotlib-wx` in the case of Suse) You'll need to install the wx backend through your package manager, as you normally would.

If you're on an OS without a package manager (e.g. windows, osx), the installer may or may not have the wx backend built depending on who built it and how it was configured. I know absolutely nothing about non-linux or BSD oses, so you're on your own there. Try looking wherever you downloaded your matplotlib binary from and see if they have a separate installer for the wx backend.

If you're building from source, you need to enable the wx backend and rebuild. To do this, edit the `site.cfg` file in your build directory. You may need to rename the default one (`site.cfg.default`, or something along those lines) to `site.cfg`, if you don't alread have a `site.cfg` file in your build directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: OR I could just keep churning out lines until something breaks a month from now then get really frustrated and spend days trying to fix it.  I'm using Windows, and I got the x64 version from Christoph Gohlke's 'unofficial' packages.